# Performing Delete operation in GridView control in ASP.NET when a Edit Operation takes place at the same time

Tags: gridview, rows, aspxgridview, cells

Currently I am using the  which is the standard way to perform Editing in a GridView control. But this allows me to perform only one operation at a time.In my application when one value of one field changes , when user clicks on "Update". Rows should be updated and also one delete query should be fired.

I tried using the manually editing

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
               AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
               DataSourceID="sdsample1" Visible="False" OnRowEditing="GridView1_OnRowEditing" OnRowUpdated="GridView1_OnRowUpdated">
```

-- Want to get the CheckboxField value of the current edit row in the backnd and its the 8 column in the gridview

```
<asp:CheckBoxField   DataField="Goal_Type" HeaderText="Goal_Type" 
                       SortExpression="Goal_Type" />


protected void GridView1_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex].FindControl("Goal_Type"));
CheckBox chk2 = ((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].Cells[7].Controls[0]);
goal_type =Convert.ToString(chk2.Checked);
if(goal_type.Equals("False"))
Goal_flag.Value ="0";
else
Goal_flag.Value = "1";
}
```

Then once I get the value of checkbox field set some flag variable , I perform a delete operation in the below function

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{

CheckBox chk2 = ((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[e.AffectedRows].Cells[7].Controls[0]);
Boolean goal_type = chk2.Checked;
if (goal_type == true && Goal_flag.Value.Equals("0"))
{

string connectionString =
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataCollectionConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd;
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.AffectedRows].FindControl("ID")).Text);
　

cmd =new SqlCommand("Delete from XXX WHERE (ID = " + ID + ") ", con);
　

cmd.CommandType =

CommandType.Text;
con.Open();

　

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();

}
```

I am getting this error at the "GridView1_OnRowEditing" function itself
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Please let me know if my approach is correct in doing the simultaneous operation in GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Use the RowEditing event for the multiple updates. As mentioned in this [issue](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q249796.aspx):

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e) {
    datasource.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE .....";
    datasource.Update(...);

    datasource.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE .....";
    datasource.Update(...);

    datasource.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE .....";
    datasource.Update(...);

    e.Cancel = true;
    ASPxGridView1.CancelEdit();
}
```

For finding the control I recommend the approach that is mentioned in this issue:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q91970.aspx

```
protected void grd_ReportChartSeries_RowUpdating(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e) {
    ASPxGridView gridView = sender as ASPxGridView;
    ASPxComboBox combo = gridView.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl(gridView.Columns["Data2"] as GridViewDataColumn, "comboData2") as ASPxComboBox;
    object data2 = combo.Value;

    combo = gridView.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl(gridView.Columns["ID"] as GridViewDataColumn, "comboID") as ASPxComboBox;
    object ID = combo.Value;

    ASPxTextBox textBox = gridView.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl(gridView.Columns["Data1"] as GridViewDataColumn, "txtData1") as ASPxTextBox;
    object data1 = textBox.Value;

    ds = Session["DataSet"] as DataSet;
    DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
    DataRow row = dataTable.Rows.Find(e.Keys[0]);
    row["ID"] = ID;
    row["Data1"] = data1;
    row["Data2"] = data2;
    gridView.CancelEdit();
    e.Cancel = true;

}
```

Or you could do the update and delete through one stored procedure call.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Employee.aspx.cs" Inherits="Class3417.Employee" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name :</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td>Gender :</td>
                    <td><asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblgender" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
                        </asp:RadioButtonList></td>
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td>Country :</td>
                    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcountry" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td>Hobbies :</td>
                    <td><asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblhobbies" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4">
                        </asp:CheckBoxList></td>
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td>Files :</td>
                    <td><asp:FileUpload ID="fufiles" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload></td>
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnsave_Click" /></td>
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" DataKeyNames="empid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="grd_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="grd_RowEditing"  OnRowDeleting="grd_RowDeleting" OnRowCancelingEdit="grd_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="grd_RowUpdating" >
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("name") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtnameedit" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("gname") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                  <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblgenderedit" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">

                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("cname") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                  <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcountryedit" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hobbies">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("Hobbies") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                 <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblhobbiesedit" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4"></asp:CheckBoxList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Files">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("files","~/uploads/{0}") %>' Width="80px" Height="60px" /> 
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                  <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="fufileedit" runat="server" ></asp:FileUpload>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
                            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />                            
                        </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>






  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.IO;

    namespace Class3417
    {
        public partial class Employee : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString);
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    Fill_Country(ddlcountry);
                    Fill_Gender(rblgender);
                    Fill_Hobbies(cblhobbies);
                    Fill_Grid();
                }
            }
            public void Fill_Grid()
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_country_gender_select", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    grd.DataSource = ds;
                    grd.DataBind();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            public void Fill_Country(DropDownList ddl)
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_country_select", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    ddl.DataValueField = "cid";
                    ddl.DataTextField = "cname";
                    ddl.DataSource = ds;
                    ddl.DataBind();
                    ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Country--", "0"));
                }
                con.Close();
            }

            public void Fill_Gender(RadioButtonList rbl)
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
                con.Open();`
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_gender_select", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    rbl.DataValueField = "gid";
                    rbl.DataTextField = "gname";
                    rbl.DataSource = ds;
                    rbl.DataBind();
                }
                con.Close();
            }

            public void Fill_Hobbies(CheckBoxList cbl)
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_hobbies_select", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    cbl.DataValueField = "hid";
                    cbl.DataTextField = "hname";
                    cbl.DataSource = ds;
                    cbl.DataBind();
                }
                con.Close();
            }

            protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string HOB = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < cblhobbies.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (cblhobbies.Items[i].Selected == true)
                    {
                        HOB += cblhobbies.Items[i].Text + ",";
                    }
                }
                HOB = HOB.TrimEnd(',');
                string FN = "";
                FN = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + Path.GetFileName(fufiles.PostedFile.FileName);
                fufiles.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("uploads" + "\\" + FN));
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_insert_update", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empid", 0);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", txtname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("gender", rblgender.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("country", ddlcountry.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("hobbies", HOB);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("files",  FN);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Fill_Grid();
            }

            protected void grd_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
            {
                grd.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
                Fill_Grid();
            }

            protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
                    {
                        DropDownList DDLC = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlcountryedit");
                        Fill_Country(DDLC);


                        RadioButtonList RBLG = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("rblgenderedit");
                        Fill_Gender(RBLG);

                        CheckBoxList CBLH = (CheckBoxList)e.Row.FindControl("cblhobbiesedit");
                        Fill_Hobbies(CBLH);

                        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
                        DDLC.SelectedValue = drv["country"].ToString();
                        RBLG.SelectedValue = drv["gender"].ToString();
                        ViewState["FL"] = drv["files"].ToString();

                        string[] arr = drv["hobbies"].ToString().Split(',');
                        CBLH.ClearSelection();
                        for (int i = 0; i < CBLH.Items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
                            {
                                if (CBLH.Items[i].Text == arr[j])
                                {
                                    CBLH.Items[i].Selected = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            protected void grd_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
            {
                grd.EditIndex = -1;
                Fill_Grid();
            }

            protected void grd_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
            {
                TextBox TBN = (TextBox)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtnameedit");
                RadioButtonList RBLGG = (RadioButtonList)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("rblgenderedit");
                DropDownList DDLCC = (DropDownList)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlcountryedit");
                CheckBoxList CBLHH = (CheckBoxList)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("cblhobbiesedit");
                FileUpload FUFF = (FileUpload)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("fufileedit");
                string IDD = grd.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();



                string HOB = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < CBLHH.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (CBLHH.Items[i].Selected == true)
                    {
                        HOB += CBLHH.Items[i].Text + ",";
                    }
                }
                HOB = HOB.TrimEnd(',');
                string FN = "";
                FN = Path.GetFileName(FUFF.PostedFile.FileName);

                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_insert_update", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empid", IDD);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", TBN.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("gender", RBLGG.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("country", DDLCC.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("hobbies", HOB);
                if (FN != "")
                {
                    FN = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + FN;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("files", FN);
                    File.Delete(Server.MapPath("uploads" + "\\" + ViewState["FL"]));
                    FUFF.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("uploads" + "\\" + FN));
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("files", ViewState["FL"]);
                }
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                grd.EditIndex = -1;
                Fill_Grid();
            }

            protected void grd_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_delete", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empid",int.Parse(grd.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Fill_Grid();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could separate view code and C# code via formatting. Also it would be nice to explain what you fixed in your approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
how to insert ,update,delete and show data in gridview  


  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Employee.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test29317.Employee" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="kk" runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name :</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td>Gender :</td>
                        <td><asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblgender" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="male" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="female" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="others" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList></td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td>Country :</td>
                        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcountry" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td>State :</td>
                        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstate" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td>Hobbies :</td>
                        <td><asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblhobbies" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4">
                             <asp:ListItem Text="cricket" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="football" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="music" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="movies" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="badminton" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="chess" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="dancing" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="dangal" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:CheckBoxList></td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td>Files :</td>
                        <td><asp:FileUpload ID="fufiles" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload></td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td>Date of Birth :</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtdob" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="call" runat="server" PopupButtonID="txtdob" PopupPosition="BottomRight" TargetControlID="txtdob"></ajax:CalendarExtender>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td>IsActive :</td>
                        <td><asp:CheckBox ID="chkisactive" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox></td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnsave_Click" /></td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="grd_RowCommand">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#Eval("name") %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#Eval("gender").ToString()=="1"?"male":Eval("gender").ToString()=="2"?"female":"others" %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#Eval("cname") %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#Eval("sname") %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hobbies">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#Eval("Hobbies") %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="date of birth">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("dob").ToString()).ToShortDateString() %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Files">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("files","~/uploads/{0}") %>' Width="80px" Height="60px" /> 
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#Eval("isactive").ToString()=="1"?"yes":"no" %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                  <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnedit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("empid") %>' CommandName="EDT"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtndelet" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("empid") %>' CommandName="Del"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>






    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.IO;

    namespace Test29317
    {
        public partial class Employee : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString);
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    Fill_Country();
                    ddlstate.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select State--", "0"));
                    Fill_Grid();
                }
            }
            public void Fill_Grid()
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_country_state_select", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    grd.DataSource = ds;
                    grd.DataBind();
                }
                con.Close();
            }

            public void Fill_Country()
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_country_select", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    ddlcountry.DataValueField = "cid";
                    ddlcountry.DataTextField = "cname";
                    ddlcountry.DataSource = ds;
                    ddlcountry.DataBind();
                    ddlcountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Country--", "0"));
                }
                con.Close();
            }

            protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string HOB = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < cblhobbies.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (cblhobbies.Items[i].Selected == true)
                    {
                        HOB += cblhobbies.Items[i].Text + ",";
                    }
                }
                HOB = HOB.TrimEnd(',');
                string FN = "";
                FN = Path.GetFileName(fufiles.PostedFile.FileName);
                if (btnsave.Text == "Save")
                {

                    fufiles.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("uploads" + "\\" + FN));

                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_insert_update", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empid", 0);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", txtname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("gender", rblgender.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("country", ddlcountry.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("state", ddlstate.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("hobbies", HOB);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dob", txtdob.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("files", DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + FN);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("isactive", chkisactive.Checked == true ? 1 : 0);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

                }
                else
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_insert_update", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empid", ViewState["ID"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", txtname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("gender", rblgender.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("country", ddlcountry.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("state", ddlstate.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("hobbies", HOB);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dob", txtdob.Text);
                    if (FN != "")
                    {
                        FN = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + FN;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("files", FN);
                        File.Delete(Server.MapPath("uploads" + "\\" + ViewState["FL"]));
                        fufiles.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("uploads" + "\\" + FN));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("files", ViewState["FL"]);
                    }
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("isactive", chkisactive.Checked == true ? 1 : 0);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                Fill_Grid();
            }
            public void Fill_State_by_country(int CIDD)
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_state_select", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
                    dv.RowFilter = "cid=" + CIDD;
                    ddlstate.DataValueField = "sid";
                    ddlstate.DataTextField = "sname";
                    ddlstate.DataSource = dv;
                    ddlstate.DataBind();
                    ddlstate.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select State--", "0"));
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            protected void ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Fill_State_by_country(int.Parse(ddlcountry.SelectedValue));
            }

            protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.CommandName == "EDT")
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_edit", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", e.CommandArgument);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        txtname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
                        rblgender.SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["gender"].ToString();
                        txtdob.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dob"].ToString();
                        ddlcountry.SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["country"].ToString();
                        Fill_State_by_country(int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["country"].ToString()));
                        ddlstate.SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["state"].ToString();
                        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["isactive"].ToString() == "1")
                        {
                            chkisactive.Checked = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            chkisactive.Checked = false;
                        }
                        string[] arr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hobbies"].ToString().Split(',');
                        cblhobbies.ClearSelection();
                        for (int i = 0; i < cblhobbies.Items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
                            {
                                if (cblhobbies.Items[i].Text == arr[j])
                                {
                                    cblhobbies.Items[i].Selected = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }




                        ViewState["FL"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["files"].ToString();
                        btnsave.Text = "Update";
                        ViewState["ID"] = e.CommandArgument;
                        con.Close();

                    }
                }

                else if (e.CommandName == "Del")
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_delete", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", e.CommandArgument);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    Fill_Grid();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```